# How do I split this certain kind of string into an array in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a string looking somewhat like this:

```
s = "'value 1', 'value 2', 'foo, bar'"
```

What I'd like to end up with is an array like this:

```
arr = ["value 1", "value 2", "foo, bar"]
```

Obviously I can't just split by comma, because there can be commas in the substrings themselves. Does anyone have a clue how to do this?

Comment: `s.split(/,\s*(?=(?:'[^']*'|[^'])+$)/)`

Comment: You can split your string on a single quote character and take every odd value, instead of using regexes

Comment: thanks, regex worked perfectly! sorry for the duplicate, thought there might be a ruby way to do this.

Comment: This is actually a well-known serialization format called *CSV*, and there is a library in the stdlib for parsing it.